# How To Obtain Remote Client SSH IP From Sudo'd Script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a small setup script which requires the user to enter their own IP address... I'm trying to make the default IP address be that of the connected SSH session.

When I run `${SSH_CLIENT%% *}` in the command line, it shows `99.99.99.99: command not found` and when I do `echo ${SSH_CLIENT%% *}` it shows just `99.99.99.99` (where `99.99.99.99` is my actual WAN IP)...

However, the following code (when ran in a bash script) shows
`[6/9] Enter your public IP address. (eg. ) :`

```bash
declare CONNECTED_IP=${SSH_CLIENT%% *}
read -e -p "[6/9] Enter your public IP address. (eg. $CONNECTED_IP) : " ipAddress
[ -z "$ipAddress" ] && ipAddress=$CONNECTED_IP
```

**Update 1**
Upon further review, it does work... except for when I run the script with `sudo`. Could someone explain this behavior to me and is there a work-around?

**Update 2**
So, it's been explained to be that this behavior is due to the fact that environment variables are not preserved when switching users (`sudo`) and that I could use the `-E` flag when executing the script to preserve the environment.

Unfortunately though, this is a script that will be shared and I therefore cannot ensure that the user executes the script with the `-E` flag. Furthermore, I don't even know if they'll use `sudo` at all.

That said, I'm looking for a consistent way to obtain the IP address of the user connected via SSH.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add it to a script file and then execute it... if I copy what I posted above into the terminal, it works fine. However, if it's in `script.sh` and I run it, no IP address is shown.

Comment: @user1960364 Since this question is no longer about `read` or variables, maybe you should rewrite it from scratch (e.g. titled "How to get client IP from a script run with sudo via ssh")

Comment: `echo "$SSH_CONNECTION"`?

Comment: Why not `alias sudo='sudo -E'` in the users `~/.bash_aliases`? If using `sudo` of course.

Comment: masseyb... firstly, that seems like a very shady practice. Secondly, by the time they've executed the script, it'd be too late.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the variable doesn't show when using `sudo` is that it doesn't automatically preserve the environment when you switch from another user. You can use the `-E` sudo option to preserve the current environment.

```
$ sudo -E ./script.sh
```

*Should show the ip as expected.*

> -E, --preserve-env
>                Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve
>                their existing environment variables.  The security policy may
>                return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve
>                the environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe that would work either because it's an install script that others will be using and I can't be sure that they'll use the flag... Is there a way from within the script itself to retrieve the previous environment?

Comment: Are the others running the install script as `sudo`?

Comment: They may, they may not... it's a script I plan to have on GitHub, so who knows how they'll run it. I'm just trying to ensure a constant behavior...

Comment: Why not use `getopts` or something of that nature? If you don't know how someone is going to execute the script or what their permissions are, etc. that can take care of most of the unknowns usually.

Comment: l'L'l, sure... that'd let me know more but it doesn't let use the IP address in all situations. Unless I'm missing the point, the only thing I could do with that is show an error with instructions on how the script is expected to be ran... which seems silly just to be able to set a default value on an input prompt. :/